# Passing a notice of invalidation to ng2-bootstrap's Timepicker

Tags: angularjs, angular, ng2-bootstrap

I am using ng2-bootstrap's `timepicker` component. I have my own validation function triggered by the `ngModelChange()` event. Now the `timepicker` component itself has its own validators (such as when the model exceeds the mix/max values) and errors are shown using the `.has-error` class. If I am doing my own validation how do I notify the `timepicker` component that it is invalid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source of the component at https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap/blob/development/components/timepicker/timepicker.component.ts, it has two public properties. Settings those should trigger the component showing an error or not.

```
  // validation
  public invalidHours:any;
  public invalidMinutes:any;
```

Comment: Unfortunately that does not seem to work. Passing a value throws this error:

`Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'invalidHours' since it isn't a known property of 'timepicker'. [ERROR ->][invalidHours]="myInvalidHours"`. I assume this happens because invalidHours is not explicitly defined as an @Input().

Comment: Those are public properties, not input properties that you can bind like you are trying to. If you reference the control with #ControlName and pass it back to the component, you can then set ControlName.invalidHours, and that will trigger the validation.